# Python: Compare array elements with float, getting a boolean list

Tags: python, list, numpy, compare

I want to compare all elements of a two-dimensional list
array with a float 
x. 
The result should be a list: 
b = [[True, False,...],...].
I tried it like that:

```
import numpy as np

array = [[a1,a2,...], [a3,a4,...],...,] 
x = 2.0

b = np.array([a >= x for a in array])`
```

`"TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'"`

When I use a one-dimensional list it works fine.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: array = `np.array([[a1,a2,...], [a3,a4,...],...,] )` and if you still get the error, that means your list elements are ragged (irregular in size).

Comment: array is a list of lists, but x. is a scalar

Comment: In you code `b = np.array([a >= x for a in array])`, since `array` is multidimensional, `a` is a list.  So in this case you are comparing `a` (a list) with `x` (a float).

Comment: `b = np.array(array) >= x`?

Comment: Can you provide  an example of a portion of `array`, say `array[:2,:2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = np.array([[a >= x for a in row] for row in array])
```